# Android PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues trouble

Tags: android, preferences

I have a problem with preference default values.
I'm trying to set a default value from xml file and then retrieve it.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int prefValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);        

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    prefValue  = settings.getInt("settingValue", 3);
    Log.v("TAGSETT", "p1 "+prefValue);

    Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("settingValue", 25);
    editor.commit();

    prefValue  = settings.getInt("settingValue", 3);
    Log.v("TAGSETT", "p2 "+prefValue);
}
```

and this is preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:key="settingValue" android:persistent="true" android:defaultValue="10"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the output:

```
p1 3
p2 25
```

but in reality I expect this:

```
p1 10
p2 25
```

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Then change your default int value to **10**,i.e. change

```
prefValue  = settings.getInt("settingValue", 3);
```

to

```
prefValue  = settings.getInt("settingValue", 10);
```

Comment: output "p1 3" means that "settingValue" is not setted in SharedPreferences. Using "prefValue=settings.getInt("settingValue",10);" prefValue get "10" not from preferences, but from the parameter passed to "settings.getInt();"